# Identify a string from its substrings

Tags: string, fewest-operations

### Introduction

I've previously created [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48089/reconstruct-a-permutation) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69799/know-a-sequence-by-its-subsequences) where the idea is to reconstruct an object using as few query-type operations as possible; this will be the third.

### The task

Your inputs shall be a non-empty string `S` over the alphabet `abc` and its length, and your output shall be `S`.
With no restrictions, this would of course be a trivial task; the catch is that you're not allowed to access `S` directly.
The only thing you're allowed to do to `S` is to call the function `num_occur(T, S)`, where `T` is some other string, and `num_occur` counts the number of occurrences of `T` in `S`.
Overlapping occurrences are counted as distinct, so `num_occur(T, S)` really returns the number of indices `i` such that

```
S[i, i+1, …, i+length(T)-1] == T
```

For example, `num_occur("aba", "cababaababb")` will return `3`.
Note also that `num_occur(S, S)` will return `1`.
The result of `num_occur("", S)` is undefined, and you should not call the function on an empty string.

In short, you should write a function or program that takes `S` and `length(S)` as inputs, calls `num_occur` on some shorter strings and `S` some number of times, reconstructs `S` from that information and returns it.

### Rules and scoring

Your goal is to write a program that makes as few calls to `num_occur` as possible.
In [this repository](https://github.com/iatorm/random-data), you will find a file called `abc_strings.txt`.
The file contains 100 strings, each on its own line, between lengths 50 and 99.
Your score is the **total number of calls to `num_occur` on these inputs**, lower score being better.
Your solution will preferably keep track of this number as it runs, and print it upon finishing.
The strings are generated by choosing uniformly random letters from `abc`; you are allowed to optimize for this method of generating the strings, but **not** the strings themselves.

There is no time limit, except that you should run your solution on the test cases before submitting it.
You solution should work for any valid input `S`, not just the test cases.

You are encouraged to share your implementation of `num_occur` too, if you're not using someone else's.
To get the ball rolling, here's an implementation in Python:

```
def num_occur(needle, haystack):
    num = 0
    for i in range(len(haystack) - len(needle) + 1):
        if haystack[i : i + len(needle)] == needle:
            num += 1
    return num
```

Comment: Does our algorithms have to work for all possible strings `S`, or just for the test cases?

Comment: @Loovjo Good question. They should theoretically work for all non-empty strings. I'll edit the challenge.

Comment: `all non-empty strings` of whatever length?

Comment: @edc65 Theoretically yes. You can ignore bounded memory addresses and other practical limitations.

Comment: It is possible to add a VW algorithm to pass the evaluation test with success: Check first for occurrence of the known strings of abc_strings.txt

Comment: @Emmanuel No. That would be optimizing for the specific test cases, which is forbidden.

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript, <s>14325</s> 14311 calls

We start with an empty string and go our way recursively by adding a new letter at the end or at the beginning of the current string while we still have at least one match.

All previous results from `numOccur()` are saved in the `sym` object and we use this data to reject immediately any new string that can't possibly be a candidate.

**EDIT**: Because we always start with `'a'`, we always know the exact number of `a` in the string. We use this information to end the process earlier when we detect that only a sequence of `a` is missing. Also fixed the regular expression which was invalid in Chrome and IE.

```
var test = [
  'ccccbcbbbbacbaaababbccaacbccaaaaccbccaaaaaabcbbbab',
  // etc.
];
var call = 0;

function guess(S, len) {
  var sym = {};
  recurse(S, len, "", sym);
  return sym.result;
}

function recurse(S, len, s, sym) {
  var dictionary = [];
  
  if(s == '' || (isCandidate(s, sym) && (sym[s] = numOccur(S, s)))) {
    if(s.length == len) {
      sym.result = s;
    }
    else if(sym['a'] && count(s, 'a') == sym['a'] - (len - s.length)) {
      dictionary = [ Array(len - s.length + 1).join('a') ];
    }
    else {
      dictionary = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
    }
    dictionary.some(function(e) {
      return recurse(S, len, s + e, sym) || recurse(S, len, e + s, sym);
    });
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isCandidate(s, sym) {
  return sym[s] === undefined && Object.keys(sym).every(function(k) {
    return count(s, k) <= sym[k];
  });
}

function count(s0, s1) {
  return (s0.match(new RegExp(s1, 'g')) || []).length;
}

function numOccur(S, s) {
  call++;
  return count(S, s);
}

test.forEach(function(S) {
  if(guess(S, S.length) != S) {
    console.log("Failed for: '" + S + "'");
  }
});
console.log(call + " calls");
```

Full executable snippet below.

```js
var test = [
  'ccccbcbbbbacbaaababbccaacbccaaaaccbccaaaaaabcbbbab',
  'caccbbababbaaaccbcabbaabaabcacabacaababcabcbbacaac',
  'bbbbaacabcabacaccaaaabaaacaacabbcbacabaccbbcbabbcbc',
  'abbcbcbccbccaacaccaccaabaccbbcabaaccabccbbbabbbcabc',
  'aabacbbbcaaabcccaccccbcaabcacaccbabbbcccacabaaababca',
  'bccbbaaccaaccacabaaaabbbbaababacabaaabacbcacbbbbabaa',
  'bbbcbcabbacbaacbacabcbabbacacbbcbcabbaabbbccbacaaacac',
  'ccbcbbbaaaaaccbaacbabbbcbccbabaabccbcbcbcbabcbbccacba',
  'aacbcbcabcbcbccbabbacacbcaaababbbcacaacaccbabbbbabcaac',
  'bcabacaabbacccacaabcaaacbcbcbacabbababcabbbbacbaaaabbb',
  'abbaccccabbbcbbaacccacbcaacababaccabbabbacbbbaabaacbaba',
  'cabbacabacccabcabacbaacbaababcaccbacbaaaacbbabbbccabbbb',
  'bcabccaaabcbaaccaabccbbcbabaccababbbaccccacaaccaccacbcab',
  'abbcbabaacbcbbabbccccbccabcbbaccacbabcacbaacbccbcabcccbc',
  'bcbacabbaabcccabccacbcbccbcbbbccacbbccaabaacccccbcabaaccc',
  'baccbcacaccacbbbcccbaaacbaccacbbacbbbaccccacbabcbbbaacabb',
  'bcccabaaaabcbbbaaccbcaccbaabacccaaacbaabaccccacabaccacbcac',
  'baabcbbcaabcacbabbcacccbcabbabaacbbbababbbbbccccccbcbbcbcc',
  'bacacbbabbcbbcaacabcccccbbacabcaabbbcbbabaacbcbbaccaaacbbac',
  'ccabccbccbaaacbcccccabacbbabbbbccbccccabaabaabbaacbabcabbcb',
  'abbaccbcaabacbbacabaabbcbacbacacabccbbcccaccbbacbbbaacbaccab',
  'bbbbaaabababcccbbbababacbacbaabbabccacccaaacabaccababaccbcac',
  'bbcbbbbcccaccbbbcbcaaccbcacaabbbbabaaabbbaaacbbaaccbacaccabbb',
  'cacabcabcbcbbbbcabbbccccccccacaaabaacbcaabbabcacbcbcccccacaab',
  'babbcacabaabbccabcbbaacccaaccbabcbbcbcbbbcabbcccbcacbabccaccac',
  'ccbbcbcbcaacbcaaccacbcaabbbcbbaccbbabacacccccaccaababcacccccba',
  'bcccbcacccccabccabccbcbccaccaaacbcacabaabcbcccaccaaaabbcacbbcaa',
  'cbbcacbbacaacbabccaabbaabacacbcbcbabcaccabbbbcabbbabaaacccaabcc',
  'aabbaacccaaacbcaabcabaabbbaababbbbcbacabbbbbbbbccaccccbbaccbbaaa',
  'abbcccabbabbaccccaacbabbccccbbbbccaaacaabacbabbabcabacbaabcbcacb',
  'bcacbccccaacbbcaccbcbcbbabacabacabbcaaabbccabcccbaacabcbbcacababb',
  'acabacaabcabbcccccbcacaccccbccaaaacacbbbccbcaabaacbbbacabcbcaabca',
  'caabbaccaacbbcbaacbcabccacacabbcbcbbacabbbaacccaacccabaaaccbbacbaa',
  'baaabbcbbbaacabacbcaaacabbacaacbacabbcabcccbabcbbacacbbababccacabc',
  'abbbacbaabcabbcabbbabaababbaabcacbabbaababcabbbccccbcaacbbcccabaccb',
  'caaababcacccaccababaccbabbccaabbbbbabaabcabccbabbbbbbcbacbabcbcccbb',
  'abbbcaaaaacaaacbbbcbacabbcbbbccacaccacacabacacbbccbbbcbaccabbcbaabbc',
  'bacacbcccabcabaabacccbcaaabcabbbcccaacbabacbaabbcccacaacbabbcacbaabb',
  'bacaaaccbaababbbbbcaabcabaacccabacccbabcbccbbcbcaacbbaabcaccaaaacaabb',
  'bbacaacccaaacacccbbacbcbbaaaccccabbbbcbbbabaaaaccbccaababaccbbccacaca',
  'aacccccbabaccbcbcbbaccbacbcbacaababaaaccbaaabaabcccccacbbaabcccaababcc',
  'babacacbbbacbbbbbabbabababacabacaaacbbccaccabacaacbabbbaccacccbcaaabbb',
  'bcaccabbabbcbcabccbbcaacbbcbacbcabaaaaaacaaacaccbcaaccaaccacbaccacaabbc',
  'acbcbbcbbaacbbbabbaabacabbcccabacabcabacccacbcaacacabcaaaabbabcccbcbabb',
  'ccbcbcccbccbbbabaabbaababbcbacacbcbaacaccccccbcbacacbcabaaaacaacbbbbacba',
  'cccbcbaaabcbbcbabbbaccabbabcacbaccbcababbababcbcaccabbbccabaabaaccccacbb',
  'bbabcbcaabbacaabcababbbccbccccaaaabaccbbbbababbcabbabbaccaaaabbcbbbcbaccc',
  'cbacaccaaaacaacbbcbbacaccabacaacacaacaacabccaaaccccacaaaaabcbcabaabaacccb',
  'bcacbccabcccabababbbbcabaacabcbbaacaaaabbbacccaaabccbaabcbbabbbcccabaabbbb',
  'cbccacabaaacabbccbacabccacabcbaccbababcccabbabbbbbbccbaabbaacaacaaaabcbabb',
  'abcbcabbcabaababccbcacabbcbcabcaabbbabbcaaabaaaaacbaabaaababccacbabcbaccbab',
  'aabbabbbcacaaaabcbcabccccacbacbccacacaabccacccaaacacbcccaabbbccacacbbccbbac',
  'caacbbccacaaaacabaacbcaaaccbbabbcacababbbabcbccbaabccaababbcbacbccababbcbbbc',
  'aaabaaaabbbbbcbbbacabccbaaaaabaacbacbcccbccacccacaaacaccbbabcbcccbbccccabbcb',
  'cccccacacbacbbcbbcabcbaabbcbbbacabcbbccccaaacabcababbcaaccaabccabaccbcaccbaba',
  'ccaaaccbccacabcacaccbccaabacacabaabbbaacbcacaacbaaabbbbabbabcccabcabbaccacacc',
  'cbbbcaccbcacccbacccaaaabacaacccbcbcbabbbaababacccccccabbaaabbcbaabbbbbbaaaaaaa',
  'ccbcbcbaabbccabbabbccbacbabacbcacbccacaabbcacaaccabbbbcbacbbcaaabaabccaacccacb',
  'caaabcabaacbbabcbccabcacbbcccabcacbbcaabaacaaabbbcacaaccaccaaaacaaccbbaaaacaaac',
  'bbacacbbaaaacbcabbbbbaabacaccabcbabbccbbbabbbacccababbcababcbbcacbababbbaaabcca',
  'bbacbbacacaccccbabbbbcabbcccbcacaabbcabbccaaaaabcbbcccaccbcbbbccabcbaccacbacbaba',
  'baccbcababbacabcbabacaababbaabcabbcbcbccabacbbaaaaabacaaacaacbacbcabacabaaccbcab',
  'accacccabccbabcbcbaababacabcabbcaccbccabbabcbcabbaabccacbbbbcaacbccaababbababbaba',
  'bbcccbcbcbccccbcaaccaaacacbbaacbcccbbcabbbccabaacbacaaaccbcbaacababaccacbcbaaccac',
  'acbccccaabcabbbcbbccbccbacbcabcccacbcabbaacbababbbcbbccacbacccbbbaccbaaaabbbabaccb',
  'babcacaccbccbaaabaabbbaabcaabaaccccacaacbaccbcbabbbbbbabcbbbbacbacbabcbbbacbbbbbbc',
  'caabcaaaaabacccacbbbaabaabccaabcbaabbcbcbbbccbabbccbcbabbbbccacbcbcbacaaccccacbbabc',
  'bbaaabbabccaccacbcbbccaaaaababbacccbabcbacabacbaacbcabaaacacaaaaacaaacabbbbccabbbca',
  'bbcbccababbbaabbabcbbaacbccbaacbababbabcbaaccbcbcabacaabacaacabcababbaaabbbbbbccccbb',
  'acabcabccaaccccacbcaabaccacaaabcbabbabbaccbbaaacacabcabbcabababaccccbcbabaacbbcccbab',
  'bacaaaaacbcacbbbaaaaabbbbcbbcbbbcaccccbacaccbbcbabbbccbaaabbcbaccacacbcbcacbcbaaabacc',
  'bbcaabccbcaccbabbacbaacacccccaabbbccbccbbbcccbacaaaccccbccbbbbabccaaacaabbbbacaacabab',
  'aaaccccbbabbcacabaacacbabbcacbcccbcbaaacaabaabacbbaabcbbbbbcacbaccaacaacbccacbbcacbbaa',
  'bbcacabcbbcbabbabbbacaaabcabbbbacbacbabacbbbbbabacabbabaabcabbaabbbaaccbcabcababcaaacc',
  'ccccbaacbbcaccaccbaaacaccbabbabaabbababcacacaaccbbcbccaaaaaaacbccacbacbabbbabcabaabaabb',
  'abacacbaccacaaacaccbcbabcaacbccaccbbacbabcababcaabcaabcbcabbcbacabaaaaaabaccccbbbcbabac',
  'ccccacbaaabaaacabbabacbbacbabcbbcaaaaacaccacabcaacabcbcbcaccabcaaccbaccabcccbccacccbacbc',
  'bcaabcaacacccbcababccacacbccccccbbaaabacabbcbbbcbaaacbbacababbaccccacbbcbacaacbabcbaccbc',
  'cbcbbaabacbaacbbcabbbbaccbaabbacbcccaaabbabacabbbababcaabcacbaccacacaccbbbbcbcbbaaacbcbba',
  'ccbcabcaabcbabbbcbcbbabacabacbbaccbbcbcabcaccaaccbaccbaacacacbbaacaaaaabcaaaacbcccbcccaaa',
  'cbbababacbbabbabaabaaaabcacbacbcccbacbccbbcaabcabaccacccbbcaacacccccaccabaabccacbaccabaaba',
  'cbbbaaacaccbcabccacbccabacbcbcccccacaccbbcccbcbbbaababcaaaacaabbbccbacbaccabccccbbbcaaaabb',
  'bbabbacaaccacccbbcabbacbcbabcccaccacbacbccababbbcacbabbbcabbbbacabcabcbaacbaabcbccacaaaccbc',
  'babcbaabccabcabaaabcaaaabaaaaccbcbcacbbbccaccccaacbcbabbbaaaccacaaabacbbabbcacbcaaaaabaabab',
  'acbabbccacaccabccbcbabacccbabbaacbccbcaabccbcbababccacbbbaabbaaaababbcaaaaabccbacbbcacbcacba',
  'cbccbbaacacccacacacbbbcbbccabcaaaabbcacacacaccbacaacbcbcbccaacaaaaaacbacacbabbbcccabbbbababa',
  'cabaabaccbbcccabaccbbacbcabbbbbaccccccbcbcbcbbccbaaabbbbcabacabccaacbcbcbabccbbcabacababccaab',
  'bccaacbabcbccaccbabcbbcbaaccbaacabbcabbbacbbccabcabccabccbacbaacbccabccaabaaabcaababacacccaac',
  'aacabcccaaccacbbcbbbbacaacacbcbcaabbcbbacbabcbccaabcbbbbaabccbbbacaababcabaacaccababacbcbccbba',
  'caaabbcbcbcabccccacacaaababbacbabacbaaccbcbabbaaacbbccccaaaabbccbcabcbccbbaaccbbbabcaabcbbbcab',
  'aacbbcbbcbaccccbaaaabcbaaabaaacaacaaacacacabaaabacbaaaacccbaaabbbcbbbacbcbccabccaabbaabcbcbccba',
  'abaccbcacabbbbacabaacaccbcbaabbaccaabbbbbababbbcbbbbacaacabbbabcaccbacabbabcbbacbbaaccbcbacaabc',
  'aacaaaacccabcccacacbaaccccababcaccaccacbbbacabccbbcbbbacaccbbbbbaabacbacbcbcabccaaccababacaabcbb',
  'baabbabaaccabcbbabcacccccaabbccbccbcaacbbbccccbbcbacaabcccccbbabbabbcacbbccbcacabbbbaaaaccbcacca',
  'aabacbaacbbccabbbacbcbbbabacaacccabbcabacacaaaabbcbbbcbbbcababbccbbacbbabcaacbacbbcaabbbcbaaaccaa',
  'aacabaaccaaabcacccabbaabbcacbabccacabaccaaaaccccccaabcbbbaabcbcccacaccbcaaacaaaabaababccbbbcccaac',
  'bcaccbcacaccbacbcccbcbbcabaabbabcccbaaababbbabbcbcbcaabbabbccccbabccabbccccabaaabccbacabccabbbacaa',
  'ccaacbabcccbabacabaccccbcbbcccbbbacbbbcccacababccbbaaaaababbabccbccabcccbccabaccbcbcacbbbaacabccaa',
  'caccbababcbcbabccabcbbaccbbbabcbacbcbcbcabcbacbcacabbcaabbbbbbbcbbaabcacccbcaabccacbccbbcccaabcbcac',
  'bbcccaabacbacbccbbbbbaabccaaabbaabcaabbcbabbbaabcbcbacbaccabacacaaaababccaaaccacaabaabcacbcaccbaabb'
];
var call = 0;

function guess(S, len) {
  var sym = {};
  recurse(S, len, "", sym);
  return sym.result;
}

function recurse(S, len, s, sym) {
  var dictionary = [];
  
  if(s == '' || (isCandidate(s, sym) && (sym[s] = numOccur(S, s)))) {
    if(s.length == len) {
      sym.result = s;
    }
    else if(sym['a'] && count(s, 'a') == sym['a'] - (len - s.length)) {
      dictionary = [ Array(len - s.length + 1).join('a') ];
    }
    else {
      dictionary = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
    }
    dictionary.some(function(e) {
      return recurse(S, len, s + e, sym) || recurse(S, len, e + s, sym);
    });
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isCandidate(s, sym) {
  return sym[s] === undefined && Object.keys(sym).every(function(k) {
    return count(s, k) <= sym[k];
  });
}

function count(s0, s1) {
  return (s0.match(new RegExp(s1, 'g')) || []).length;
}

function numOccur(S, s) {
  call++;
  return count(S, s);
}

test.forEach(function(S) {
  if(guess(S, S.length) != S) {
    console.log("Failed for: '" + S + "'");
  }
});
console.log(call + " calls");
```

Comment: "In short, you should write a function or program that [...], reconstructs S from that information and **returns it**."

Comment: @KarlKastor - Oops. You're right. That's fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 15205 calls

```
def findS(S, len_s, alphabeth = "abc"):
    if len_s == 0:
        return ""
    current = ""
    add_at_start = True
    while len(current) < len_s:
        worked = False 
        for letter in alphabeth:
            if add_at_start:
                current_new = current + letter
            else:
                current_new = letter + current
            if num_occur(current_new, S) > 0:
                current = current_new
                worked = True
                break
        if not worked:
            add_at_start = False
    return current
```

This submission is most likely suboptimal, because it only uses `num_occur` to check if a string is a substring of `S`, and it never uses it to actually count the amount of substrings.

The algorithm works by storing a string `current` which is built up to be equal to `S` in the end. Here are all the steps in the algorithm:

1. We set `current` equal to `''`
2. Go through each letter in the alphabet, and do the following:

   2.1. Create a new string `current_new`, and set it equals to `current` followed by the letter.

   2.2. Check if `current_new` is included in `S` by running `num_occur` on it and see if the result is greater than one.

   2.3. If `current_new` is included in `S`, set `current` to `current_new` and go back to step 2. Else, we go to the next letter.
3. If the length of `current` is equal to the length of `S` we can say that we are done. Else, we go back to step 2, but modify step 2.1 to make `current_new` equal to the letter followed by `current` instead. When we reach this step again, we are done.

Comment: Python's for loop has an else clause. This would be a perfect use case for it.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>14952</s> 14754 calls

Very similar to the first answer, but doesn't try next characters which result in impossible substrings that:

- we know from `num_occur` that they don't occur in the target (from previous calls)
- we already used the substring more often than it occurs according to `num_occur`

<s>(will add counting of substrings in a minute)</s> done

```
def get_that_string(h,l,alpha = "abc"):
    dic = {}
    s = ""
    ##costs 1 additional call per example, but its worth it
    char_list = [num_occur(j,h) for j in alpha[:-1]]
    char_list.append(l - sum(char_list))
    for y, z in zip(char_list,alpha):
        dic[z] = y
    end_reached = False
    while len(s) < l:
        for t in alpha:
            if not end_reached:
                neu_s = s + t
                substrings = [neu_s[i:]   for i in range(len(neu_s))]
            else:
                neu_s = t + s
                substrings = [neu_s[:i+1] for i in range(len(neu_s))]
            ## Test if we know that that can't be the next char
            all_in_d = [suff for suff in substrings if suff in dic.keys()]
            poss=all(map(dic.get,all_in_d))
            if poss:
                if not neu_s in dic.keys():
                    dic[neu_s] = num_occur(neu_s,h)
                if dic[neu_s] > 0:
                    s=neu_s
                    for suff in all_in_d:
                        dic[suff] -= 1
                    break
        else:
            end_reached = True
    ##print s
    return s


## test suite start
import urllib

def num_occur(needle, haystack):
    global calls
    calls += 1
    num = 0
    for i in range(len(haystack) - len(needle) + 1):
        if haystack[i : i + len(needle)] == needle:
            num += 1
    return num

calls = 0
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iatorm/random-data/master/abc_strings.txt"
inputs = urllib.urlopen(url).read().split("\n")
print "Check: ", inputs == map(lambda h: get_that_string(h, len(h)), inputs)
print "Calls: ", calls
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python <s>12705</s>  12632 calls

1. make a list of 2 characters strings occurrences
2. sort the list
3. build the string trying the most probable character first, don't test if there is only one possibility
4. update the list
5. if the list is empty it is finished else step 2

*I used Loovjo function skeleton. I never code in Python I needed a bootsrap*

**EDIT:**
*Added code for one character length strings*
*Added code to reject already matched patterns*

```
def finds(S):

    if len(S) == 0:
            return ""
    if len(S) == 1 
            if num_occur("a",S) == 1 :
                         return "a"
            if num_occur("b",S) == 1 :
                         return "b"
            return "c"
    tuples=[]
    alphabet=[ "aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc", "ca", "cb"]
    for s in alphabet : tuples.append( (num_occur(s,S), s) )

    sum=0
    for (i,s) in tuples :   sum+=i
    tuples.append( (len(S)-sum-1, "cc") )
    tuples.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))

    (i, current) = tuples[0]
    tuples[0] = (i-1, current)

    add_at_start = True
    nomatch=[]
    while len(tuples) > 0:
            worked = False
            tuples.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
            count=0
            if not add_at_start :
                    for (n, s) in tuples :
                            if s[0]==current[-1:] :         count+=1
            for i in range(len(tuples)):
                    (n, s)=tuples[i]
                    if add_at_start:
                            if current[0] == s[1] :
                                    current_new = s[0] + current
                                    possible=True
                                    for nm in nomatch :
                                            lng=len(nm)
                                            if current_new[0:lng] == nm :
                                                    possible=False
                                                    break
                                    if possible and num_occur(current_new, S) > 0:
                                            current = current_new
                                            worked = True
                                    else :
                                            nomatch.append(current_new)
                    else:
                            if current[-1:] == s[0] :
                                    current_new =  current + s[1]
                                    possible=True
                                    for nm in nomatch :
                                            lng=len(nm)
                                            if current_new[-lng:] == nm :
                                                    possible=False
                                                    break
                                    if count == 1 or (possible and num_occur(current_new, S) > 0) :
                                            current = current_new
                                            worked = True
                                    else :
                                            nomatch.append(current_new)
                    if worked :
                            if n == 1:
                                    del tuples[i]
                            else    :
                                    tuples[i] = (n-1, s)
                            break
            if not worked:
                    add_at_start = False
    return current
```

Comment: no 'cc' in your alphabet?

Comment: @Sparr "cc" is calculated, that's saves 100 calls : ` tuples.append( (len(S)-sum-1, "cc") ) `